# How can I configure IntelliJ IDEA to allow a shebang in Java files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, preprocessor, shebang

**Context:**

I often use a [Java launching shebang](http://patrodyne.org/sites/scripting-JavaBang/) to make my Java source files runnable as if they were scripts. I also regularly run projects directly out of IntelliJ IDEA. Many of my Java files start with `#!/path/to/my/java/launcher`.

I realize that this practice is questionable in all but the most basic of testing scenarios, but that's all I use it for.

This is convenient because I often run tests on multiple different servers when not testing locally in IDEA. It's cumbersome to point IDEA to different remote servers to run code on them, and much easier to just go to those servers (the code is already there, as it's stored on a network share) and run files with `./MyFile.java`, or instruct others to do the same.

**Problem:**

If I have a file with a Java shebang in IDEA, it won't compile. The `#!` line (and the rest of the file) is detected as a syntax error by the IDE.

**Question:**

How do I configure IDEA to work with Java files containing a technically-invalid-syntax shebang?

Ideally, I'd be able to tell IDEA to "disregard lines that are first and start with `#!` in .java files when syntax-checking/compiling". However, I'd also be happy if I could configure a blanket "ignore the first line of all .java files when syntax-checking/compiling" rule.

Put more fundamentally: **how do I get IDEA to support (compile, consider to be valid) Java files that contain a `#!`-prefixed first line?**

**What I've Tried:**

- I tried hacking the invocation of `javac` used by IDEA to use pipes/anonymous file descriptors and `tail` to exclude the first line; no such luck.
- I've tried adding artifacts to strip out the first line as part of the build process, but this doesn't seem to help the syntax validation issue: even if the offending lines would be stripped out during the build, IDEA thinks the whole file is invalid syntax and can't be built.
- I've tried using annotations to suppress the error, but those prevent the shebang from being on the first line, at which point the file can't be run as if it were a script.
- I've tried messing with inspections in IDEA, but the fundamental compilation check behavior doesn't seem to be configurable (via the inspections interface, at least).

Comment: Why not modify this shebang-thing, so that it would detect //#! ?

Comment: If it is possible to pass this as a command line parameter, then you can do that.

Comment: @WernerKvalemVesterås: The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is a hard-coded constraint of POSIX systems. The shebang line must start with `#!` and be the first characters in the file; it can't, to my knowledge, be modified to use a different magic word like `//#!`.

Comment: @WeareBorg: the whole point of using the shebang is so command line parameters do not have to be used when invoking small script-like Java files; is that what you mean? If there's a parameter I can supply to IDEA's invocation of `javac` to accomplish this, that would solve my problem.

Comment: For "the most basic of testing scenarios" what's so bad about `javac MyFile.java && java MyFile`?  If your testing scenarios are so complex you can't just do that, you should use a proper build script or system.

Comment: A shebang is _not_ valid Java, so IDEA is quite right in marking that line as an error. The fact that you have some other program that takes an improper Java source file and does something useful with it, doesn't make that source file valid Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a build-and-run script unacceptable for some reason?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

CLASSPATH="..."

javac -cp "$CLASSPATH" "$1"
java -cp "$CLASSPATH:." "$1"
```

That seems no worse (and in fact better, since it's obvious and standard) than the shebang solution you link to, since it also relies on an external file.

Comment: "...then you will see it is not the spoon that bends, it is only yourself." If your tests are so hard you have to change your IDE to get them to work, it's time to come up with a better way to write your tests.

Comment: A build-and-run script is what was previously used. Testers (they're used to scripting languages, and have next to no experience with Java/compiled languages in general) kept having issues using little Java programs because they were running the old versions of JARs. It was determined that they could not be trusted to rebuild them on their own. Since there's no deployment system, and binary files aren't allowed in source control (the directory on NFS), the shebang solution was found to be the remaining option. That's the Y to this XY problem, but it's sadly not soluble that I can see.

Comment: It sounds like you should limit the code you give to testers to languages they understand, then.

Comment: Regrettably, that is probably the approach I will have to take. The constraints of the problem are silly, to be sure, and not related to the design of Java/IDEA, but them's the brakes.